# Post-build event copy not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, post-build-event

I have a post-build event to copy a .dll from one project to another on successful build using the following command:

copy $(TargetPath) ....\MainProject\bin

This works fine on my local machine, but it appears to be failing on the build server because when building the MainProject I receive the following:

warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Project2". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

Has anyone experienced similar issues with the copy command in a post-build event?

Answer (score 2):

That warning isn't from the Copy task, it is from the build of a project.  Crank up the diagnostic level and log to a file (/fl /flp:v=diag;logfile=diag.txt) to see where the warning is actually coming from.